# Wolfram Alpha can plot an equation but not solve it

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to solve the equation

$24.6347 \left(246.347 x + \sqrt{(246.347 x + 20)^2 + 1} + 20\right)^{-a} =\\ 30.2879 \left(-33.6532 x + \sqrt{x (1132.54 x - 20191.9) + 90001} + 300\right)^{-a}$

for $a>0$ but Wolfram Alpha doesn't give me a solution. It is however able to plot my equation ([wolfram output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B24.6347+(246.347+x+%2B+sqrt((246.347+x+%2B+20)%5E2+%2B+1)+%2B+20)%5E(-a)+%3D+30.2879+(-33.6532+x+%2B+sqrt(x+(1132.54+x+-+20191.9)+%2B+90001)+%2B+300)%5E(-a),+a%3E0%7D)). Am I doing something wrong and if not, is there another way to obtain a solution to this equation?

Comment: Do you mean you want to express $a$ in terms of $x$, or $x$ in terms of $a$, or something else?

Comment: I want to express x in terms of a to get the same plot wolfram alpha gives me in tex via pgfplots.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Comment: I tried to reformat your post using MathJax.  Please check that it still says what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

That equation does not have a closed form expression (formula) for $a$ in terns of $x$ or $x$ in terms of $a$. If you know one of them you can use numerical methods to find the other. That's what Wolfram alpha is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your equation in Wolfram Mathematica and I got a solution but it's not a nice one (a whole screen full of numbers). However, if you just want to graph $x$ as a function of $a,$ I'd suggest you use some other program to make an image which you can use however you like. Here are a couple of examples from Wolfram Mathematica and GeoGebra. The latter is free.
[image: Made in Wolfram Mathematica][image: Made in GeoGebra]